# Get JSON Arrays specific values in list

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout

I have below JSON and I want to get the `name` and `label` of all blocks in one list. How I can get it using Apex?

```
{
  "name":"A",
  "label":"as",
  "prefix":"mr",
  "data":"ad",
  "subject":"das"
},
{
  "name":"B",
  "label":"w1",
  "prefix":"dasd",
  "data":"asda",
  "subject":""
},
{
  "name":"C"
  "label":"ds"
  "prefix":"",
  "data":"dasd",
  "subject":"ada"
}
```

I tried with code below but not getting how to get only Name and column (key and values) in other list

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest); 

        string jsonResponse=httpResponse.getBody();
        Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonResponse);
        List<Object> lstCustomers = (List<Object>)results.get('sobjects');

        for (Object customer : lstCustomers) {
 // now get attributes for this customer.
```

My Output needs to be

```
Map{Name:'A',"b','c'}
```

Comment: Did you check if the given JSON string is valid?

Comment: This is just an example to understand query

Comment: Where does it fail? Are you getting an error? It might also be helpful to see the code you're using to attempt to access each `customer` object in the `for` loop.

Comment: I stuck .how i can achive this result..Map{Name:'A',"b','c'}

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, it seems that the JSON example you provided is not a valid JSON (missing ',' between elements), I know it is just an example, but if you are using an array then it should have been enclosed with `[` and `]`.

Now coming to the requirement, assuming that it is an array, JSON's [`deserializeUntyped`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) returns `Object` which means it depends on what kind of `JSON` is passed, so in your case it will return `List<Object>` as your input is an array of `JSON`

In order to get the data in the format that you have specified, you will have to follow 3 steps.

1. Get the response in `List<Object>` using JSON.deserializeUntyped
2. Convert `List<Object>` to `List<Map<string,Object>>` by typecasting each element inside the `list`
3. Get the response in the format you need from the `List<Map<string,Object>>`

This is how your code should be which can be optimized if needed

```
//First step : Get the response in List<Object>
string jsonResponse ='[{"name":"A","label":"as","prefix":"mr","data":"ad","subject":"das"},{"name":"B","label":"w1","prefix":"dasd","data":"asda","subject":""},{"name":"C","label":"ds","prefix":"","data":"dasd","subject":"ada"}]';
List<Object> lstCustomers = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonResponse);

//Second step : Convert List<Object> to List<Map<string,Object>> by typecasting each element inside the list
List<Map<String, Object>> allMaps = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
for(Object cust : lstCustomers){
    allMaps.add((Map<String, Object>)cust);
}

//Third step : Get the response in the format you need from the List<Map<string,Object>>
Map<string, List<Object>> finalMap = new Map<string, List<Object>>();
for(Map<String, Object> cus : allMaps){
    for(string key : cus.keyset()){
        if(finalMap.containsKey(key)){
            finalMap.get(key).add(cus.get(key));
        }else {
            List<Object> newObj = new List<Object>();
            newObj.add(cus.get(key));
            finalMap.put(key,newObj);
        }
    }
}
system.debug(finalMap);
system.debug(finalMap.get('name'));
system.debug(finalMap.get('label'));
//and so on for other attributes
```

Comment: ajay what Vijay is proposing it works fine.. change the system.debug(finalMap); for System.debug(finalMap.get('name')); and you will get what you want.

Comment: @Ajay the above code should work for you